# Parity upgrade error parity: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found (required by parity)

Tags: linux, ethereum, parity

I am using ubuntu 14.0 system, parity version 1.9.7 when upgrading the ethereum parity node. An error occurred.

parity: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found (required by parity)
parity: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: version`OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found (required by parity)
parity: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by parity)
parity: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version`GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by parity)
parity: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by parity)